# Why isn't the scripts in my autoload folder being executed in Vim?

Tags: vim, gvim

I'm trying to use Pathogen to manage my Vim extensions. My bundle folder looks like this:

```
.../bundle/
├── vim-pathogen
│   └── autoload
│       └── pathogen.vim
└── vim-smoothscroll
    └── autoload
        └── smooth_scroll.vim
```

And my vimrc file includes this:

```
let s:root = fnamemodify(resolve(expand(":p")), ":h")

" Initiate pathogen.
exec "source " . s:root . "/vimfiles/bundle/vim-pathogen/autoload/pathogen.vim"
exec pathogen#infect()
```

My vimrc file is a symlink located in *~* but pointing to a folder inside my Dropbox folder.

This appears to work when I start Vim. Pathogen has added `vim-smoothscroll` to my runtimepath:

```
:set runtimepath?
runtimepath=~/Dropbox/Personal/config_sync/vim/vimfiles,~/Dropbox/Personal/config_sync/vim/vimfiles/bundle/vim-p
athogen,~/Dropbox/Personal/config_sync/vim/vimfiles/bundle/vim-smoothscroll,~/.vim,~/vim/share/vim/vimfiles,~/vim/
share/vim/vim74,~/vim/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after
```

The problem is that the script `smooth_scroll.vim` hasn't been loaded:

```
  1: ~/.vimrc
  2: ~/Dropbox/Personal/config_sync/vim/vimfiles/bundle/vim-pathogen/autoload/pathogen.vim
  3: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  5: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  7: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/menu.vim
  8: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/autoload/paste.vim
  9: ~/Dropbox/Personal/config_sync/vim/vimfiles/colors/codeschool.vim
 10: ~/Dropbox/Personal/config_sync/vim/_vimrc_gui
 11: ~/Dropbox/Personal/config_sync/vim/_vimrc_keybinds
 12: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 13: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
 14: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 15: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 16: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 17: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
 18: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 19: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
 20: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 21: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 22: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/syntax/ruby.vim
 23: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/syntax/vim.vim
 24: ~/vim/share/vim/vim74/syntax/python.vim
```

Why is that? Loading the script manually works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are doing *crazy* things with your setup. Did you find the default way too easy and solid?

- Vim's runtime files, everything under `/share/vim/vim74`, should be in `/usr/share/vim/vim74`. Did you install Vim in your `$HOME` because of privilege issues?
- All your personal stuff (colorschemes, plugins, syntax scripts...) must go into `~/.vim`. That directory can be a symlink to that `vimfiles` directory in your Dropbox which would remove the "need" for all your hacks. Assuming you are on Linux, just do:

  ```
  ln -s /home/username/Dropbox/Personal/config_sync/vim/vimfiles /home/username/.vim
  ```
- `pathogen.vim` is *not* supposed to be `source`d like that. It's in the `autoload` directory precisely because the `autoload` mechanism *prevents* it to be `source`d in order to save time at startup.

  Additionally, `pathogen.vim` should be in `~/.vim/autoload/`.

  With a "normal" setup, or a symlink that makes it look "normal" to Vim, there's no need to go through all those hoops.
- `smooth_scroll.vim` should not be in an `autoload` directory, it comes in a `plugin` directory, why did you change that? That's why the plugin doesn't work.
- Did you know that 7.4 now looks both for `~/.vimrc` *and* for `~/.vim/vimrc`? It makes it a lot easier to manage your config by keeping everything in a single directory.

**Step 1:** change the structure of that `vimfiles` directory in your dropbox to look like this:

```
/home/username/Dropbox/Personal/config_sync/vim/vimfiles/
  +-autoload/
  |   +-pathogen.vim
  +-bundle/
      +-vim-smoothscroll/
        +-plugin/
          +-smooth_scroll.vim
```

**Step 2:** move your `vimrc` inside the `vimfiles` directory in your dropbox.

**step 3:** remove all the useless path-related stuff in that file. The pathogen-related part should look like this:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()
```

**step 4:** remove your `~/.vimrc`:

```
$ cd
$ unlink .vimrc
```

**step 5:** create a symlink to your dropbox-synced directory:

```
$ ln -s /home/username/Dropbox/Personal/config_sync/vim/vimfiles /home/username/.vim
```

Comment: @Mokubai, I'm currently writing a detailed answer, thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood the roles of the plugin and autoload folders. I assumed "autoload" meant that the script would be loaded on startup, which is exactly what the plugin folder is for. As for "`pathogen.vim` is not meant to be `source`d like that", that is incorrect. I pretty much copied it from the [`Pathogen`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) FAQ. I actually didn't know that Vim searches for `vimrc` inside `~/.vim`, so I'll be sure to clean up my setup a bit. Also, I installed vim to `$HOME` just because I prefer it. No need to `sudo` all the time, and it's easier to clean.

Comment: In older versions, Vim can be made look for ~/.vim/vimrc by setting `VIMINIT=":so ~/.vim/vimrc"` in the environment.

Comment: @Codemonkey, you are wrong. In its simplest form, what you do is `source pathogen.vim`, and *nothing* in pathogen's `README` tells you to do that. The fact that `pathogen.vim` is in `autoload` means that it is and should *never* be sourced at all. That's the whole point of `autoload`. `execute pathogen#infect()`, the correct line given in pathogen's `README`, is not at all the same as what you do. About the location of the `vimrc`, it's new in 7.4. About the location of your Vim install, why would you need to `sudo` all the time?

Comment: @romainl: Scroll down to the FAQ and observe the line: `source ~/src/vim/bundle/vim-pathogen/autoload/pathogen.vim`

Comment: It only applies if you use Git to keep your config in sync *and* add pathogen as a submodule. Since you don't, that part is totally irrelevant. Sticking with the default install method and not messing around is the easiest way to have a working and dependable config. Also, what's with that "sudo all the time"?

Comment: @romainl: I want to keep all scripts that *I didn't make* under `bundle/`, that's why Pathogen is there. As for "no need to sudo all the time", I try to keep everything I build inside my user folder, including MySQL, Python, Ruby etc. because then they won't affect the whole system, plus I don't need to invoke `sudo` so often which reduces the chances of me damaging the system accidentally.

Comment: OK, those reasons are all valid in my opinion but installing Vim is not really the kind of operation that could mess with your system.

Comment: @romainl: You're probably right, but I tend to recompile a lot (in experimentation) and it's just so much easier to `rm -rf ~/vim` than to manually uninstall a system Vim :) I haven't checked if the Vim makefile has an uninstall command though, this is just how I'm used to do it.

Comment: Yeah. To me, it looks like a rather big sacrifice to go through all those hoops and hacks just for such a little bit of convenience. Simplicity is gold.